# What happens when answering an incoming FaceTime call from an Apple Watch?

Tags: ios

If an incoming FaceTime call is received on an iPhone paired to an Apple Watch, the call will ring both on the phone and the Watch. I realise that it's not currently possible to make/receive FaceTime calls on an Apple Watch directly due to the lack of a camera, but if a FaceTime call is answered on an Apple Watch, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s an audio call only.

You can make audio cellular calls, so it stands to reason FaceTime would follow suit.

This [article](https://www.imore.com/how-make-facetime-call-apple-watch) expands on using FaceTime audio on the Apple Watch